# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/tmatesoft/svn/core/SVNException

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, svnkit

I want to achieve SVN checkout, commit, update function in my eclipse plugin project.

So I added External JAR "`org.tmatesoft.svnkit_1.7.9`" in build path.

However when I run my plugin project, there is "`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/tmatesoft/svn/core/SVNException`" exception occurring.

And in "`Overview`" window I click "Update the classpath settings", this JAR package disappeared.

When I installed `subclipse` plugin, this problem got solved, but I do not want all my plugin users to install `subclipse`.

Can anyone please help me out with this issue?

Thanks in advance!